# Is $p \implies q \implies r$ equivalent to $(p \implies q) \implies r$ or $p \implies (q \implies r)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

Should I give priority to the rightmost or the leftmost operator in this case?

In my textbook, it says that $p \implies q \implies r$ is equivalent to $$p \implies (q \implies r)$$ but, when I input in a online calculator such as this one: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/formular-uk-zentral.html
$$p \implies q \implies r$$

the resulting table truth is the same as the one for
$$(p \implies q) \implies r$$

So, which one is wrong in this case?

Comment: "$p\Rightarrow q\Rightarrow r$" is ambiguous. It is neither *equivalent* to "$p\Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow r)$" nor to "$(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow r$". It can be *defined* as "$p\Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow r)$" or as "$(p\Rightarrow q)\Rightarrow r$". However I don't think theres a widely accepted definition in this case. And so generally raw "$p\Rightarrow q\Rightarrow r$" should be avoided. And answering your question: both are correct, they just defined it differently.

Comment: It should be $p\implies(q\implies r)$ or you lose the correspondence with curried functions, with $(r^q)^p \equiv r^{pq} $, with categorial exponential objects, etc.

Comment: This is like the argument about whether $0^0=0$ or $0^0=1$. Sure, you could define it  either way, and sometimes people do, but there are deep reasons why it should be $1$ and not $0$.

Comment: Most people don't have to care, because they encounter nested implications so infrequently. When they do, they can just include parentheses to clarify which one they mean. A minority (e.g. proof theorists, category theorists. some computer scientist) do have to care, because they encounter nested implications frequently. And the members of this latter group *always* choose $p \rightarrow q \rightarrow r$ to stand for $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$: it happens to be much more convenient than the alternative. So if you have to choose, following your textbook makes more sense in this case.